# Processing a high transaction data queue over webservices

Tags: .net, json, multithreading, web-services, fifo

I have the following scenario:

1. On the client end, there is a component reading messages from a `oracle/sql` table which acts like a data queue.
2. The data is sent via http calls to an http page which processes the data one call at a time
3. Once the call is returned the record (message) is deleted from the queue

Both the components above are `.Net` components.  I am facing the following issues with the above:

1.The process only manages to send about 5-6 calls/sec, is multi-threading the only option to speed up this process.

1. What are the best practices to manage `exceptions`/ failures. e.g. should i send a message, delete it from the queue and then wait up on the status or should i send message, await the status and then delete it.  In either cases what should happen if the call fails, what is the best way to retry the message, keep it in the queue or move it to a separate queue and have a separate component retry it later.
2. Will using `json` instead of `XML`, speed things up.

I would appreciate any feedback you guys can provide.  If this seems like a duplicate post I do apologise.  Are there any best practices or models for the above scenario.

Comment: If your service is capable of processing 5-6 calls/sec it means that serialization time is insignificant.

Comment: Before solutioning it would be better to identify where the bottleneck is. For example, how long does the target http page take to process the request.

Comment: @NickRyan There are two bottlenecks the way we see it.
The first one is the backend stored proc that processes the incoming data on the target http page.  It basically validates the data for each request and then inserts it in to the DB.
The second one is on the client side component, since each record has to be deleted after recieving the status from the target http page, and moved to an archive queue. The opening of the connection and the subsequent delete also seems to take some time.